# the function of "as" in the following sentence

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

"But so far, we haven't seen a groundswell of private donations as we often see in major disasters."

In the sentence above, is "as" a conjunction or a relative pronoun?

I ask this question because I think there should be an objective after "see" if "as" is an conjunction.

Comment: It looks ill-formed to me. I'd expect "But so far, we haven't seen such a groundswell of private donations as we often see in major disasters." or "But so far, we haven't seen a groundswell of private donations such as we often see in major disasters." or "But so far, we haven't seen the groundswell of private donations [that] we often see in major disasters." // "But so far, we haven't seen a groundswell of private donations (as we often do in major disasters)." also works. Even with the second 'see', though then there's a hint of ambiguity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The original text is fine. Your suggested alternatives aren't much better, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

*As* is being used as a [subordinating conjunction](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subordinating_conjunctions.htm) in the "comparison" category.

*We haven't seen a groundswell of private donations* is the main clause.  *We often see in major disasters* is the subordinate clause.

---

You do make an interesting observation, though: the sentence is very close in meaning to

> But so far, we haven't seen *the* groundswell of private donations *that* we often see in major disasters.

*That* would be a relative pronoun, whose antecedent is *donations*.

Comment: 'We haven't seen a dog as we often see at the weekend' doesn't sound acceptable to me.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree. What's your point?

Comment: He is saying the OP sentence is ill-formed.

Comment: The OP sentence is clear to me, and its form seems fine. It might be less problematic to some if it appeared in context so that readers would be primed to understand that the writer is (I assume) comparing donations observed *so far (in a period affected by a major disaster)* to donations observed in similar periods in the past.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence you provide "as" is used to compare one action to another and denotes a meaning ***in the way or manner that*** or ***like***

In your case, the writer compares the action of "seeing groundswell of private donations"

"As" being a "subordinating conjunction" (sometimes called a dependent word) comes at the beginning of a subordinate clause and establishes the relationship between the dependent clause and the rest of the sentence.

```
It came out the same way as it did before.
```

Please [check](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/as?s=t)

Answer (score -1):

"as" has a lot of uses (too many in my view), but it can't be used as a relative pronoun.